# Creating A Web Game Having Issues With A Function

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently working on a game for browsers strictly built with php, html, sql & js atm. It's just a fun project i'm working on. Yet I have come to a spot where a function is not working as intended and maybe some help can help me find where I am going wrong. So with that said I have a page where you can fight enemies. Now once you hit the attack button it calculates a formula then updates the enemy health according to the enemies current health - so called formula. Now that works as intended. I moved on to then make the opposite (when an enemy attacks me) and it is not working as intended. It always, no matter what, sets the character health to 0 instead of running the correct formula etc. `$enemy` & `$my_character` are arrays.

```
$enemy = Array ( [level] => 1 [cur_health] => 104 [max_health] => 108 [cur_mana] => 36 [max_mana] => 36 [defense] => 30 [attack_power] => 16 [spell_power] => 3 [image] => images/enemies/demon_1.png [name] => Demon [battleback] => images/battlebacks/cave1.png )

$my_character = Array ( [name] => rackemup [level] => 1 [next_level] => 2 [avatar] => 05.png [class] => Knight [race] => Human [max_health] => 135 [current_health] => 135 [max_mana] => 9 [current_mana] => 9 [next_level_xp] => 100 [current_xp] => 30 [sp] => 0 [gold] => 115 [tokens] => 0 [ac] => 0 [defense] => 18 [attack_power] => 20 [spell_power] => 1 )
```

Controller:

```
if ($action == "attack") {

  charAttack($enemy,$my_character);

  enemyAttack($enemy,$my_character);

  header("Location: ?route=$route&msg=2#attack");
  exit;

}
```

Model:

```
function enemyAttack($enemy,$my_character) {
  $dmg = $enemy['attack_power'] - $my_character['defense'];
  if ($dmg <= 0) {
    $dmg = 1;
  }else{
    $dmg = ceil($dmg);
  }
  $cur_hp = $my_character['cur_health'] - $dmg;
  updateCharacter($_SESSION['char'],"health",$cur_hp);
  updateLog("Enemy Attack","The Enemy Hit You For ".number_format($dmg)." Damage!");
}

function charAttack($enemy,$my_character) {
  $dmg = $my_character['attack_power'] - $enemy['defense'];
  if ($dmg <= 0) {
    $dmg = 1;
  }else{
    $dmg = ceil($dmg);
  }
  $cur_hp = $enemy['cur_health'] - $dmg;
  updateEnemy($_SESSION['char'],"health",$cur_hp);
  updateLog("User Attack","Your Attack Hit The Enemy For ".number_format($dmg)." Damage!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$my_character['current_health']` instead of `$my_character['cur_health']` in `enemyAttack`?  ;-)